# onConnected() not being called to get location updates (GooglePlayApi for location)

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

So i have this code:

```
package com.entu.bocterapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class LocationManager implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private Context mContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public LocationManager(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    //
    if (checkIfGooglePlayServicesAreAvailable()) {
        //Get Access to the google service api
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } else {
        //Use Android Location Services
        //TODO:
    }
}

public Location getCoarseLocation() {
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        return mLastLocation;
    } else return null;
}

private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

private boolean checkIfGooglePlayServicesAreAvailable() {
    int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
    if (errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, (RecentSightings) mContext, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        Toast.makeText(mContext, location.getLongitude() + " , " + location.getLatitude() + " : " + location.getAccuracy(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "suspended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

}
```

I am trying to get location in this class, but onConnected() never gets called(i waited for 1-2 minutes). I went with the debugger, it says google play services are available.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I'm stuck here for hours, reading everything, and can't get it to work.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you checking if onConnectionFailed is called? Put a breakpoint there and you'll probably find your answer.

Comment: Nope, no luck. It does not call onConnectionFailed() either.

Comment: The callbacks usually happen in less than a second. Are you sure connect is getting called?

Comment: buildGoogleApiClient();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();

Comment: Are you running on a phone or simulator? Are you sure that `checkIfGooglePlayServicesAreAvailable` is returning true?

Answer (score 12):

You must call

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if(mGoogleApiClient!=null){

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if(mGoogleApiClient!=null){

        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }

    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem just updated my grade version `:10.0.1'` to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
```

it works.